# How to access to a folder host via a docker container?

Tags: java, scala, docker, jenkins, containers

I'm actually stuck with the problem of a shared file.

I want to access my host folders so I did something like this in my Jenkinsfile :

```
sh "sudo docker run -d -it -p 16000:16000 -v /PATH/TO/MY/HOST/FOLDER/:/var/tmp --name botvolume MY_IMAGE"
```

And in my scala class I'm trying to get all the folders by using :

```
val folders: Array[File] = new File("/PATH/TO/MY/HOST/FOLDER/") 
  .listFiles
  .filter(_.isDirectory)
```

But it's doesn't work, it returns a size equal to 0.

I read [the docker volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried starting the container and logging into it via shell?

Comment: Hi Daniu, sorry I didn't see your message. I will try and come back to you, thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the container the volume path is `/var/tmp`

Then your code should be :

```
val folders: Array[File] = new File("/var/tmp/") 
  .listFiles
  .filter(_.isDirectory)
```

You can find the detail on the Docker volume bind syntax on the link you provided:

-v or --volume: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters **(:)**. 
The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.

- In the case of bind mounts, the first field is the path to the file or directory on the host machine.
- The second field is **the path where the file or directory will be mounted in the container**.
- The third field is optional, and is a comma-separated list of options

Comment: Hi Guillaume, Thank you for answering ! =) 

I change my code by yours but still a problem. 
I add a println to return the size of "folders" but still 0   and I know there are subfolders.

Comment: as @daniu said in its comment hve you tried starting the container mnually and logging into it via shell to check the mounted content in "/var/tmp/"?

Comment: Oups, I didn't see his message. I will try and come back to you

Comment: Thank you for your help Guillaume and Daniu.

You were right for the path.

And my second problem

I change my code by yours but still a problem. I add a println to return the size of "folders" but still 0 and I know there are subfolders.

It was because I had some issues with my main class so the docker stopped directly after start. I resolved it too =)